# Tinymce on keypress I am try to display the preview of the content

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce

I am trying below code

```
 $('textarea.tinymce').keypress(function(){
      dealDescription = $('textarea.tinymce').tinymce().execCommand('mcePreview');
      $("#deal_preview div").text(dealDescription);
 });
```

But I am not using jquery tinymce editor suppose I use jquery tinymce and other jquery UI component not working properly so I am directly using the tinymce component.

Now I need to show content preview in preview box for each key press.

Answer (score 3):

Im using this in tinymce 4.x

```
tinymce.init({
    selector: "#tinymce-textarea",
    setup : function(ed) {
        ed.on("change", function(e){
            $('#tinymce-livepreview').html(tinymce.activeEditor.getContent());
        });
        ed.on("keyup", function(){
            $('#tinymce-livepreview').html(tinymce.activeEditor.getContent());
        });
   }
});
```

**Explanation:**

on("change") is for detect changes on mouse event if u click toolbar icon or selection from the menu. It also able to detect the keyboard event but only after lost focus (not real time).

on("keyup") is for detect changes on real time keyboard event

Answer (score 1):

Could be done after initialisasing as well by getting the active editor:

```
tinyMCE.activeEditor.on('keyup', function () {
    // your nicely formatted code here
});
```

There's also an `editors` array you can iterate over if you need it.

Answer (score 0):

I try with below code is working fine

```
tinyMCE.init({

    mode : "exact",
    elements : "text",

    setup : function (theEditor) {
        theEditor.onKeyPress.add(
            function (theEditor) {
                previewContent(theEditor);
            }
        );
    },
});

function previewContent(editorObject){
     var content = editorObject.getContent();
     document.getElementById("previewContent").innerHTML = content;
}
```