# php textarea automatic save to sql with jquery/ajax

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, textarea

I know this question has been asked before, and I have read several suggestions and answers, but I can't get it to work.

I have a textarea on a php page, and I want to get the content of the textarea saved to a sql database while the user is typing or every 2-5 seconds without the page being reloaded.

I believe it has to be made with jquery and Ajax?

The content is saved to the database if I make it as a POST form with a save button - so I know the sql is functioning.

I have those files:
todo.php

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js'></script>
<form method='post' action='notes.php'>
<table border='0' cellspacing='0' width='480px' height='250px' align='center' id='logo-table'>
<tr>
<td align='center' height='10px' valign='top'><textarea type='text' id='notes_input' name='notes_input' style='width: 460px; height: 230px; border:0px;'>$data[notes]</textarea></td>
</tr>
</table>
<input type='image' src='/nycrm/grafik/Save-as.png' name='gem' value='Submit' />
</form>
```

and script.php

```
<?php
require_once 'connect.php';
session_start();
$ses_userid = $_SESSION['ses_userid'];
$notes_input = $_POST["notes_input"]; 

mysqli_query($connect_intra, "UPDATE user SET notes = '$notes_input' where userid = '$ses_userid'");
 ?>
```

I tried this code which I found here on stackoverflow, but it seems like the code is not being executed - in this case the todo.php looks like this:

```
<?php

$ses_userid = $_SESSION['ses_userid'];
$query =  mysqli_query($connect_intra, "SELECT notes FROM user WHERE userid = '$ses_userid'");
$data = mysqli_fetch_array($query);

echo"
<script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js\"></script>
<script type=\"text/javascript\">
$(\"#notes_input\").bind(\"keydown\", function() { myAjaxFunction(this.value); });

function myAjaxFunction(value) {
$.ajax({
    url: \"script.php\",
    type: \"POST\",
    data: \"notes_input=\" + value,
    success: function(data) {
        if (!data) {
            alert(\"unable to save file!\");
        }
    }
});
}
</script>
<form method='post' action='notes.php'>
<table border='0' cellspacing='0' width='480px' height='250px' align='center' id='logo-table'>
<tr>
<td align='center' height='10px' valign='top'><textarea type='text' id='notes_input' name='notes_input' style='width: 460px; height: 230px; border:0px;'>$data[notes]</textarea></td>
</tr>
</table>
<input type='image' src='/nycrm/grafik/Save-as.png' name='gem' value='Submit'/>
</form>
";
?>
```

Do I miss something so it will work?

Your help is much appreciated.

/Thomas.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST` or `$_GET` data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: Hi Tadman Thanks for your answer. Sorry for my ignorance, but is this better?   '$sql="UPDATE user SET notes = '$notes_input' where userid = '$ses_userid' LIMIT 1";
  $result = mysqli_query($connect_intra, $sql);'

Comment: You really need to avoid putting things like `$notes_input` in your query in the first place. Try: `UPDATE user SET notes=? WHERE userid=? LIMIT 1` and then `bind_param` to set those two values. Normally you update a note based on the note's ID, not the user. The `LIMIT 1` thing here seems like a mistake.

Comment: Thanks again. I managed to get it work with bind_param.. :) But I stil miss the jQuery/Ajax part..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Browser reads HTML from top to bottom. When it find script tag it pause parsing and evaluate script.

In your example, when second script starts, textarea don't exists yet.
 Because of that `jquery` can't find any node with id `notes_input`, it just create empty jquery object to prevent errors in further functions.

You should move second script (with `.bind` statement) to end of `body` tag or wrap biding to `jquery.ready` function. It will delay execution of script until page fully parsed.

Comment: Fantastic.. It works! Thanks very much. After I posted this question, i added TinyMCE to the textarea's. I found out that if TinyMCE is activated it doesn't save while typing, but if I deactivate TinyMCE it works?

Comment: TinyMCE, probably, replace your binding with thir own. If you want to get events with TinyMCE you need listen their events. [Check this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5765981/tinymce-on-keypress-i-am-try-to-display-the-preview-of-the-content)